# Existence of a certain limit at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$ be a locally integrable function. Does the following limit necessarily exist?

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \liminf_{\delta \to \infty} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{[\delta, \delta + \varepsilon]} f(x) \ dx $$

Comment: Yes, by Fekete lemma (liminf of $\int_\delta^{\delta+\varepsilon}$ is superadditive as a function of $\varepsilon$)

Comment: Wow that’s slick..